# show remaining file count when removing files on multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote following [fiddle to](http://jsfiddle.net/kezputha/70enapfb/) select multiple files

but in this program once I remove files using `X` icon its not showing how many files currently remaining

**Picture 1**

[image]

After I remove a file view is like below

**Picture 2**

[image]

this is the whole code snippet foe above program

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload"  multiple="multiple"/>
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function(){
    $(this).parents('span').remove();

})

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {

    var filename = this.value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
    var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     $("#upload_prev").append('<span>'+'<div class="filenameupload">'+files[i].name+'</div>'+'<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
    }    
});
```

**CSS**

```
.filenameupload {
    width:98%;  
}

#upload_prev {
    border:thin solid #000;
    width: 65%;
    padding:0.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
}

#upload_prev span {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

How can I modify this program to show how many files currency remaining when I remove files using close icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text that you are highlighting in your pictures, i.e. the "2 files selected", only shows a file count when you click the "Choose files" button (or "Browse..." button, etc., depending on which browser you're using) and you select multiple files. When you click the same button and choose a single file, it will not say "1 file selected" but will rather simple show the name of the file. Moreover, it will be reset after every new button click. For example, if you click the button and choose "fileA.txt" it will display "fileA.txt". If you click again and choose both "fileB.txt" and "fileC.txt" it will show "2 files selected" even though it will now show 3 files.

To actually provide a total count of the total number of files selected you need to count them yourself and provide your own tally. I've shown this in the code below by doing the following:

- create a variable that keeps track of the total number of files
- putting an extra `<div id="file_count"></div>` before your other html
- creating a new function called `showFileCount` that inserts the file count into that `div`
- calling `showFileCount` once at the very beginning
- incrementing the count by the number of most-recently-selected-files in the 'change' handler and then calling `showFileCount`
- decrementing the count by one in the 'click' handler and then calling `showFileCount`

```js
var fileCount = 0;

var showFileCount = function() {
  $('#file_count').text('# Files selected: ' + fileCount);
};

showFileCount();

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).parents('span').remove();
  fileCount -= 1;
  showFileCount();
})

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {

  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    $("#upload_prev").append('<span>' + '<div class="filenameupload">' + files[i].name + ' abc</div>' + '<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
  }
  fileCount += files.length;
  showFileCount();
});
```

```css
.filenameupload {
  width: 98%;
}

#upload_prev {
  border: thin solid #000;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
}

#upload_prev span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_count"></div>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to hide `File input text`

Comment: @Andrew Willems, can you pls upload with file size

Comment: If you're asking if I can, for example, show the file size in the list of files chosen, then I think that that goes beyond what the OP was asking for, and thus is not really appropriate in this answer. If you want to find out how to do that, I would encourage to search for other questions or even ask your own. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the File input text from your code. The only value you can set is empty string

```
$('#uploadFile').val("");
```

I would suggest you to create a div/span to show the selected files count. You can decrement this count whenever you delete a file

Make the value empty [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xo6bwb0s/1/)

**Edit**
If you hide the file input you cannot select files from your computer. You can set the opacity to 0 though.

```
#uploadFile {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xo6bwb0s/2/)

In this case you need to have another element to select the File input. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xo6bwb0s/3/)

Comment: is there anyway to hide `File input text`

Comment: I tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/kezputha/70enapfb/4/ according to this example http://jsfiddle.net/xvLAc/1/